# Moving Office 365 sync to a new Essentials server

Tags: windows-server-essentials, office365

I have decommissioned an old Windows Server 2008 server which was running Azure AD Connect.

A new Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials server was promoted as DC on the existing domain.

I am trying to setup Office 365 integration using the inbuilt service utility but get the following "there was an issue configuring the integration" error message.

[image: There was an issue configuring the integration]

Can someone please help?

The log file SharedServiceHost-EmailProviderServiceConfig.log contains the error:

```
[8848] 181204.124303.7219: UpdateO365IntegrationDataTask: Failed to get all users : O365ConfigurationFault = NotActivatedMicrosoft.WindowsServerSolutions.O365Integration.O365ConfigureException: Operation cannot be called if O365 is not activated on the box yet   at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.O365Integration.O365ManagementCore.CheckState()   at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.O365Integration.O365ManagementCore.QueryAllOnlineUsersInternal(Boolean throwOnFault)   at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.O365Integration.UpdateO365IntegrationDataTask.Run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before where the issue was a value in the registry was not updated to contain the DC's FQDN:

Check below registry key and make sure that the key “Value date” is Windows Server 2016 Essentials’ FQDN (system – full computer name):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Server\ADContext
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. There isn't a key called Value Date, however key ConnectedDc under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Server\ADContext has the server's correct FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect with Essentials is only supported with Windows 2019. Maybe this is the reason you get this error.